# God and the devil make a bet

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book, poetry

God and the Devil wager about man's worthiness. Devil has cat's eyes. He chastises God for causing suffering in the first place.

It didn't sound like poetry, but it must be one of the few takes on the Book of Job that was only a few paragraphs long. The Devil says man is only good because God takes care of them. So God rains down calamities, and humanity keeps worshipping him. See how good and loving they are? And finally the Devil says, but you kept punishing them, what does that say about you?

I know this is a long shot. It was a single-page contribution in one of those sci-fi anthologies, probably 80s or 90s.

Comment: Long shot, but does "The Contest" from https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45518/short-story-god-and-the-devil-watching-the-average-life-of-john-smith?rq=1 spark any memories?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Job#Prologue_on_Earth_and_in_Heaven